# Не получаю 200 ответ из запроса android retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Делаю запрос для получения информации с сервера. В логах видно что информация загружается и все нормально. Я пробую вставить в условие в запросе вывод сообщения в логи о том что запрос удачен. Вот сам запрос:

```
 sp = getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
 a_token = sp.getString("access_token", "");
 MySingleton.getInstance().apiService().get_15_list("Bearer " + a_token).enqueue(new Callback<Last_15_jobs>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Last_15_jobs> call, @NonNull Response<Last_15_jobs> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    jobModelArrayList = (ArrayList<JobModel>)Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getJobs();
                    Log.w("MY_TAG", "success");
                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("refresh_token_expired")) {

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Last_15_jobs> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

и я не вижу в логах что запрос удачен, хотя при послании запроса я получаю положительный ответ. Вроде все сделал как всегда но почему то не получаю уведомление в логи и не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось поискать ошибку очень долго и тщательно. Очень долго думал что умельцы апи криво сделали и мне нужно будет с ними ругаться. Готовился уже все им рассказать, но потом решил посмотреть свой класс-модель который я использую при вытаскивании данных из ответа. И оказалось что я ОЧЕНЬ жестко протупил)) Типы данных указал совсем не те, и как результат - программа не могла понять почему ответ не соответствует тому что я прописал в модели.

Мораль сей басни такова: нужно проверять все до мелочей и постараться максимально прошерстить свой код, чтобы случайно не обвинить коллег или других разрабов в их некомпетентности.

Я не уверен что данный вопрос чем-то поможет кому-то кроме меня, но я советую каждому чекать все что вы пишите. Удачи всем :)

Answer (score 2):

Наверное ломается но строчке

```
jobModelArrayList = (ArrayList<JobModel>)Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getJobs();
```

и не проходит дальше. Преобразования правильные **(ArrayList< JobModel >)**?

p.s.

> В логах видно что информация загружается и все нормально

Как это видно? В onResponse попадает если breakPoint поставить?

Comment: в логах видно что запрос шлется и есть информация с сервера

Comment: break point не срабатывает почему-то

Comment: наверное падает с ошибкой в onFailure. Выводи в onFailure Log

Comment: хммм... лог вывелся в onFailure. Теперь вообще ничего не понятно, почему не работает?

Comment: чтобы понять нужен лог ошибок

Comment: В onFailure какая ошибка приходит?

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "http://server.net/ang/showangex.php3?sid=jnagjid&idang=440197894"   вот ошибка в логах

Comment: говорит что вы пытаетесь строку преобразовать в число. Значит неправильно сформирован модель Last_15_jobs. Где-то приходит String, а у вас в модели ожидается Int

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87275/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-duosduo).